# Raspberry Pi as mosca mqtt broker,Node-Red and MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mqtt, node-red, mosca

I'm working on a school project and I'm a little bit overwhelmed. Is the first time that I work with mqtt service and Node-Red. In the structure of the project I have a Raspberry Pi communicated through gpio with a dht11 sensor, I want to communicate the RPi with my VPS where Node-Red is hosted. Finally this Node-Red working as suscriber in mqtt service has to save the data of measures in a MongoDB database and show the data in a graph. Can someone explain me how to communicate RPi and Node? RPi can work as broker and client in mqtt at the same time? Sorry for my English I'm learning.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the following doc about how to ask good questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

MQTT is a client (subscriber/publisher) server (broker) process.

Both the broker (mosca) and the client can run on a computer (RPi, VPS).

Check that the RPi is the best place for the broker. Your VPS (virtual private server) must have a connection to the broker. If the RPi is behind a firewall in your private network, you need to open an inbound port!